# Уместно ли продолжение речи автора после приведения цитаты?

Tags: узус

Как Вы считаете, уместна ли такая конструкция:

В предложении 24 говорится: "Родину надо защищать", - и это свидетельствует о патриотическом настрое Кузьмы.

Предложение от балды. Интересует именно сама схема. И если после цитаты авторское высказывание продолжить можно, то какие знаки препинания должны стоять? (В моем примере это ",-" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложенный вариант знаков препинания - правилен. Цитаты оформляются так же, как и прямая речь.

> 1. Когда авторский текст предшествует цитате, то он отделяется двоеточием. ***У М. Алигер есть строки: «Человеку надо очень мало, чтобы счастье выросло в полный рост».***
> 2. Когда авторский текст следует за цитатой, то он отделяется запятой с последующим тире. ***«Тот не писатель, кто не прибавил к зрению человека хотя бы немного зоркости», — сказал К. Паустовский.***

В предложении о Кузьме используются оба правила:

> ***В предложении 24 говорится: «Родину надо защищать», — и это свидетельствует о патриотическом настрое Кузьмы.***

[Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Знаки препинания при цитатах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, если исходное предложение выглядит, допустим так:

> "Родину надо защищать", - и это свидетельствует о патриотическом настрое Кузьмы.

То процитировать его можно так:

> В предложении 24 говорится: «"Родину надо защищать", - и это свидетельствует о патриотическом настрое Кузьмы.»

(виды кавычек можно поменять местами).

Comment: Для вложенных кавычек существует полиграфическое правило: "ёлочки" для внешних кавычек, а "лапки" для внутренних. Например:  _В кино пойдёшь? Сегодня дают «Как я опоздал на „Титаник“»._ [Типографические стандарты: кавычки](http://artefact.lib.ru/design/text_macros_05_quotes_typo.shtml)